# Knowing the language used in a form

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm working on a site with forms that require a certain language to be used. (Something like a dictionary). I want to know if there is a way in JavaScript/HTML to check the language. For example, if I need the input in Japanese and the user gives me an English word, it is detected as an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) and there's an [example of language detection](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to do this with straight java/html.  The best you could do is hope that UTF-8 is the encoding, and then you check the character class.  But that still doesn't really tell you which language is used.

Comment: Not to be annoying, but Java is not the same as JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to implement a function or use a specific library.